# Rails: How to add a newly created user's email address to MailChimp?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp

For context, I am developing a web application using Ruby on Rails and I am using MailChimp for handling email campaigns.

Given an ActiveRecord Model named User with an attribute named email, how might I send a user's email to a MailChimp List upon the successful creation of a new user?

Comment: As a good learner and contributor, if you found any answer useful, you should upvote for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, what you need is [Callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/activerecord_validations_callbacks.html#available-callbacks). You can write code to subscribe your new user to mailchimp in `after_create` callback.

Something like in your `user.rb` model.

```
def after_create(user)
  # code to subscribe user to mailchimp
end
```

You can have a look on this [blog](https://www.uludum.org/courses/120-ruby-on-rails-recipes/subsections/2180-integrating-mailchimp-with-your-rails-application) for more and an example.

Answer (score 8):

Add the official `mailchimp-api` gem to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'mailchimp-api', require: 'mailchimp'
```

Then run:

```
bundle install
```

Use an `after_create` hook in your User model to send the subscriber to MailChimp:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_create :add_mailchimp_subscriber


  def add_mailchimp_subscriber
    client = Mailchimp::API.new('<your mailchimp api key>')
    client.lists.subscribe('<your mailchimp list id>', {email: email}, {'FNAME' => first_name, 'LNAME' => last_name})
  end
end
```

That's the minimum you'll need to add the subscriber to MailChimp. You may want to move the add_mailchimp_subscriber logic to it's own class or queue a job to run it asynchronously. You should also add some error handling. The `client.lists.subscribe` method will raise errors specific to the problem. For example, if the MailChimp list id you specify is not valid you will get a `Mailchimp::ListDoesNotExistError`.

You can find the official gem and docs here:

https://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mailchimp-api-ruby/

Comment: Perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mailchimp API for managing list subscribers: http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/subscribe.php

There are several ruby wrappers for ease of use in rails: http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/downloads/#ruby-rails

So, the common approach to add some actions on model changes is to use Active Records callbacks. So your code may look like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_create :add_subscriber_to_list

  private

  def add_subscriber_to_list
    # Logic to add subscriber to list via Mailchimp API ruby wrapper
  end
end
```